# How can I export my messages from Outlook XP into text files with directories for mail folders?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

How can I export my emails from Outlook XP into text files and have it create directories for my corresponding mail folders?

Comment: I assume that you are starting with a PST file? May I ask your purpose for exporting them specifically into TXT files? Depending on your answer, there may be other ways to do what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Also, are you looking for each e-mail to be a separate TXT file?

Comment: That's correct, within folders which mirror my outlook mail folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used codetwo's [outlook export tool](http://www.codetwo.com/freeware/outlook-export/) (its free) successfully to CSV text files.

Comment: Does it create folders?

Comment: I just checked; it doesn't and there isn't a field "by directory" in the chooser. Unfortunate - I thought it would.

Comment: Does the tool mention the folder name somewhere inside the exported files it generates?

Comment: No, not that I've seen

Answer (score 1):

OK... I think this works.

1. Select all groups of messages. (ex. today yesterday...) then click to send to OneNote (or print to OneNote...)
2. Once in OneNote, save it as a PDF.
3. Once in a PDF format, convert it to text.

Comment: I'm using outlook xp, see edit.

Answer (score 1):

Taking what Fergus proposed a step further: Using the [outlook export tool](http://www.codetwo.com/freeware/outlook-export/) just export one folder at a time. Then take the resulting files, and stuff them in a folder that way. Unless you have a crazy amount of folders it should not be that bad.

Comment: As mention on the other comment to an answer, this doesn't create folders.

Comment: "and stuff them in a folder that way" manually. Its not ideal.

Comment: I've loads of folders, wanted to do my archive pst too, which goes back years