# Export mails from outlook folders into the file system - not as pst

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, archiving

I would like to save (kind of archive) my emails from a specific folder in outlook to my file system.
At best I would like to "clone" my outlook folder structure and save everything in it to my file system.

I need each mail separately as a file.

Until now I only found the PST archive method and the method of saving each mail 1 by 1.

What are the other options?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I export my messages from Outlook XP into text files with directories for mail folders?](http://superuser.com/questions/289798/how-can-i-export-my-messages-from-outlook-xp-into-text-files-with-directories-fo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can multiselect, then drag and drop emails from your Outlook Inbox (or whatever folder) to a folder on your desktop (or wherever).

Comment: Sometimes the solution is easy and wonderful. Thank you sir

Comment: Any way to copy folder + subfolder in a fast way? This way I can only get the current folders mails.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to drag and drop folders.